# How does this Fibonacci series code work?

Tags: python

I don't understand what the end sign means in this code.

```
def fib(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while a < n :
        print (a,end='')

        a = b
        b = a+b

        print()

fib(5)
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the Fibonnaci series.

Comment: I suggest you change the topic to be relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full signature of the [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function is:

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

The "end" paramter is the suffix appened to each print.
The default value is '\n' which is a new line.

```
def fib(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while a < n :
        print(a)
        a = b
        b = a+b

fib(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are encountering unknown Python construct, it can be often explained by built-in Python `help`. Simply launch python console and do `help(print)` to get description of `print`, which is as follows:

```
Help on built-in function print in module builtins:

print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

    Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
    Optional keyword arguments:
    file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
    sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
    end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
    flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
```